# Cómo me conecto a una base de datos alojada en la web con MYSQL For EXCEL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, mysqlconnector, excel-2013

Estoy haciendo pruebas en un servidor local y funciona bien. Puedo administrar todas mis tablas que cree en phpmyadmin de forma dinámica con Excel 2013. El problema es que no se como establecer la conexión cuando la base de datos no está en un servidor local, sino que está alojada en la web. Qué host name debería poner? Que puerto debería usar? No se si sirva de ayuda, pero aquí dejo el enlace de mi sitio de pruebas: https://sitiodepruebadebasesdedatos.000webhostapp.com/
Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Saludos. Esos datos te los proporcionan al momento que contratas el hosting; adicionalmente el usuario que usas para conectarte debe tener permisos para conectarse remotamente (es decir, en tu caso, desde tu ubicación).

Comment: En efecto era eso amigo. Resulta que el servicio de hosting que tengo no admite conexión remota a MySQL. Muchas gracias! Queda entonces encontrar un hosting que si me permita administrar de manera remota las bases de datos de mi sitio.